# Return Iterator without Remove method

Tags: java, iterator, overriding

I have multiple lists and for a specific list (in the example list b), I must return an iterator which doesn't have/allow remove method, I must preserve the information:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    List<E> a = new ArrayList<E>;
    List<E> b = new ArrayList<E>;

    b.add("A");
    b.add("B");
    b.add("C");
    myMethod();
    }

    public Iterator<E> myMethod(){
      return b.iterator();
    }
```

I can't change the "public Iterator myMethod()", how is possible to return the iterator for b, without Remove method?

Comment: [Protects an given iterator by preventing calls to remove(). : Iterator « Collections « Java Tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/Protectsangiveniteratorbypreventingcallstoremove.htm) (found very easy using my search engine, you should try yours too).

Comment: @OleV.V. provided a link that explains a possible answer to your issue.

Comment: @OleV.V. I cannot change the "public Iterator<E> myMethod. How can I implement the class you linked above?

Comment: You would just need to keep your iterator  implementation generic, i.e. `class ReadOnlyIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {... public E next() {..` etc but I would not bother because using an unmodifiable list is much less work. The example is fairly old code from before generics were introduced to java in 1.5.

Comment: @zapl write it has answer, I am going to mark it has correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(b).iterator();
```

This seems to me to be the easy way out. The unmodifiable view on your list ensures that the iterator you get cannot modify the list, that is, the `remove` method will not work and should throw an exception, an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

**EDIT:** Since you can’t change `myMethod`, there are two options, or really, variants:

1. Make `b` unmodifiable altogether. This will only be acceptable if you don’t need to make modifications of `b` at all, of course.
2. Make `b` an unmodifiable view onto a list that can be modified through some other view of the same list.

Code example for 1., in Java 8 and earlier:

```
    List<String> b = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
```

In Java 9 and later it’s simpler:

```
    List<String> b = List.of("A", "B", "C");
```

`List.of` produces an unmodifiable list.

In case a completely unmodifiable list doesn’t fit your requirements, here a suggestion for code fro option 2.:

```
    List<String> modifiableB = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    List<String> b = Collections.unmodifiableList(modifiableB);
```

Now `myMethod` will access `b`, that is, the unmodifiable view, and therefore produce an iterator that cannot remove elements, whereas other methods can modify `b` through `modifiableB`.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the iterator of an unmodifiable list wrapping the original list:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(b).iterator();
```